# I joined two objects together, but when I edit the object, they aren't completely joined

Tags: mesh, objects, bones

I am currently making a bird in Blender, and I accidentally separated the wing of the bird from the body. After realizing I didn't need to separate the objects, I then rejoined them back together (control J).

Now I am adding bones to the object, but when the wings flap, you can see a hole in the bird's body where I separated the objects. How do I completely join the wing back to the body so this hole doesn't exist[image]?

Answer (score 1):

You have two edge loops that overlap perfectly, one on the body, the other on the wing. To fix the issue, select everything, then press <kbd>W</kbd> and choose remove doubles.